# If I don't get an answer does it mean I am right?

Tags: discussion

I was asking whether something is true or not : In the form of : Can I say that ..... is true?

If I don't get an answer does it mean I am correct?

[characterization of homomorphisms $K^{m\times n}\rightarrow K^{m'\times n'}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3702123/characterization-of-homomorphisms-km-times-n-rightarrow-km-times-n)

Comment: I always find verification questions difficult. A "no" answer is easy (finding a flaw or a counter-example), but verifying a "yes" requires more work, and it can be embarrassing if you provide a "yes" answer only for someone to prove that it is actually "no"!

Comment: Below you wrote (commenting on an Answer), " Maybe they want me to think about it and see that I am right...".  Maybe.  Certainly the standard for proof in mathematics is what convinces one with reasoned mathematical argument.  The absence of proof is not proof of absence.

Comment: If I have taken the time to verify whether your something is true or not, I will certainly leave at least a comment to that effect.

Comment: Is [this the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3702123/charachteisation-of-homomorphisms-km-times-n-rightarrow-km-times-n) you are asking about?  You asked this meta question after only one hour of that post's submission. Answers don't flow in immediately, in a lot of cases, and posting here only one hour after submitting a question a bit premature. If it is another question you are asking about, please edit your post to include a link to the question.

Comment: @amWhy yes this is the question I was refering to

Comment: Why *would* it mean that? Is this a serious question, and you’re just genuinely this confused, or are you actually fishing for an answer to your original post?

Answer (score 14):

No, that's not a safe conclusion to draw.  Unfortunately there are many possible reasons why you're not getting an answer (you haven't linked to your question for us to evaluate it) and without any prior knowledge none of them are any more likely than the others.

You *might* conclude, however, that your question is not well-asked and could be improved by editing, or asking someone(here, maybe; chatrooms, maybe; a trustworthy friend) for an honest opinion of it.  Even if you can find little to improve, making those improvements would bump it to the front-page and fresh eyes will see it and might answer.  (This is *not* encouragement to edit it just to get to the front-page!  It's just to explain why a good edit can help you.)

Comment: but people would really bother to just write a yes? Maybe they want me to think about it and see that I am right and there is nothing to worry about - my question got lots of views

Comment: @New2Math It depends :)  I think most people would refuse to write a one-word answer as it feels lazy and unhelpful, even if "Yes" or "No" is all that's required.  You might well get a comment saying "Yes" or "No" however.

Comment: Technically, users **can't** write a one-word answer, or even a one-word comment (unless that one word is at least 15 characters long). There are ways to get around these restrictions, but they are not encouraged. I have seen users post a comment along the lines of "Yes, that's correct," I've even left such comments myself, but it's hard to know what to read into it if no one comments at all.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3702123/characterization-of-homomorphisms-km-times-n-rightarrow-km-times-n